# Switch website Name Servers without or with minimal downtime?

Tags: networking, email, dns, nameserver, cname

**Facts:**

- My domain name is registered at Namecheap.
- My website is hosted on Netlify via an "A" & a "CNAME" record that points to them.
- My email MX records are Google's.

**The issue:**

Although I'm not hosting the website with Namecheap, I do have a hosting plan bought from last year that is associated with my domain name in question.

This is about to expire within the next 5 days and I do not want to renew it since I don't use it.

The problem is **all my A/CNAME/MX records are all set from within the cPanel associated with my domain name.** If I don't pay the hosting for another year, I will have to switch to Namecheap Basic DNS and my website and email will be down for up to 48 hours, which is not acceptable.

Is there any way around this?

Please help, I appreciate any input on this matter.

PS: I found this potential solution by creating a new "A" record but I don't think it applies to my situation since I have to do it from inside cPanel: https://serverfault.com/a/817737/447014

Comment: Why would this cause your DNS to go down for 48 hours?  I don't use namecheap for DNS, but why can't you set up a zone file with Namecheap FreeDNS which mirrors the zone in your cPanel account, then change the DNS servers ?

Comment: (if you get really stuck, email me at superuser at my.host.net.nz with the name of your zone, and I can temporarily set you up with a zone on my nameservers, which will allow you to shift away from cPanel without downtime, and you can then focus on a zone set up on a permanent nameservers which you can move to.)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change to FreeDNS. I get this error "Not Eligible for FreeDNS. This domain is already registered under your own account." after following the steps here: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/536/51/how-do-i-set-my-domain-to-use-namecheaps-freedns-service

Comment: I see what you are saying, but, reading that link, why would Basic DNS not work?

Comment: Why is there a 48 hour downtime? Are you sure it's not a delay - during which time the domains could be fed from the existing CPANEL?

Comment: So you're saying that if I click on *Basic DNS* right now (switching from *Website Hosting DNS*) and add my 5 MX records (Google's) and my CNAME & A record pointing to Netlify then I won't experience downtime? What do you mean by "fed from the existing CPANEL" exactly? If I switch isn't the website automatically offline?

Comment: I would imagine that to be the case, but as I said, I don't use namecheap DNS, so I could be wrong. By fed from existing CPANEL, I mean set  up using the same data that's in CPanel - the records you just mentioned.

Comment: A few weeks ago only I *misclicked* on Custom DNS (from Basic DNS) on another domain on Namecheap and I ended up not receiving email for 48 hours and the website did not resolve for 24 hours. I assumed this would happen with all switches.

Comment: Someone on Reddit suggested I make the switch and if I quickly enter the 7 records in Basic DNS I will experience little to no downtime but I'm not sure about that: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/7hofr6/switch_name_servers_without_or_with_minimal/dqsl5xp/

Comment: What he is saying would sound right to me. Why don't you seek clarification with namecheap support? I note the general way to do DNS changes is to prepare the new DNS, then switch nameservers.